# Show $f: S \to S$ st. $|f(x)-f(y)|≤ {1 \over 2}|x-y| ~\forall ~ x,y \in S$ where $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a finite subset, has a fixed point

Tags: functions

If $f: \mathbb{S} \to \mathbb{S}$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|≤\frac{|x-y|}{2}$ $\forall ~ x,y \in S$ where $S$ is a **finite subset** of $\mathbb{R}$, show that $\exists k\in \mathbb{S}$ such that $f(k)=k$.

---

Why does this seem immensely easy yet not doable? First of all, we can arrange the elements of the set $\mathbb{S}$ in an increasing order, that is, $\mathbb{S}=\{a_i~ |~ a_r<a_s \text{ for } r<s, i \in [1,n]\cap \mathbb{N} \}$. Now, observe that if $|a_i - a_j|$ is minimal for $i=p, j=q$ such that $p\neq q$, then $|f(a_i)-f(a_j)|\leq \frac{|a_i-a_j|}{2}$ is itself a contradiction unless $f(a_i)=f(a_j)$ as otherwise, we will result into obtaining $|a_i-a_j|\leq |f(a_i)-f(a_j)|\leq \frac{1}{2} {|a_i-a_j|}$. (The first inequality is direct from the fact that the function maps from $\mathbb{S}$ to $\mathbb{S}$ and that $|a_i-a_j|$ is minimal.

I couldn't proceed any further.

Just to show an example,

If $\mathbb{S}=\{1,2.1,3.2,4,4.25\}$, then, $f(1)=f(2.1)=f(3.2)=4 ~ ; ~ f(4)=f(4.25)=4.25$ seems to be a valid example!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $m = \min_x|f(x)-x|= |f(x^*)-x^*|$, then $m \le |f(f(x^*))-f(x^*) | \le {1 \over 2} |f(x^*)-x^*| = {m \over 2}$ and so $m = 0$.

Comment: What's $x^*$? (If it's another variable, in not sure how that might hold true always)

Comment: @Mathbg It appears to describe the value [or: a value] $x$ at which the expression $|f(x) - x|$ attains its minimum. [This minimum is guaranteed to exist since $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ is finite: there are only finitely many elements in $S$ for which the above-mentioned expression can be evaluated. Do this, and pick an element that achieves the minimum.]

Comment: @BenjaminDickman My bad! I didn't realise that you kind of defined another function, let's say $g(x)=|f(x)-x|$ which assumes the minimum at $g(x^*)$. I had assumed $x$ to be that minimum point. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: I defined nothing: I'm not the answerer! But, you are welcome RE: clarification.